# Reusing elements in JavaScript templating engines

Tags: javascript, html, performance, template-engine

My question is about how JS templating engines work.

For example, I have template that looks like this:

```
<div class="my-block"> 
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <p>{{description}}</p>
</div>
```

... and with data:

```
{
   title: 'Hello',
   description: 'World'
}
```

... it renders into DOM element that is saved into some variable (simply by replacing `{{title}}` and `{{description}}` with `String replace()` (something like [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)):

```
<div class="my-block"> 
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <p>World</p>
</div>
```

Only one element of such type is present at once, but values in it (title and descrition) are changed pretty frequently.

How can I avoid creating DOM element each time (`.my-block`), and replace `{{title}}` and `{{description}}` of existing element automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some markup to your code

```
<div class="my-block"> 
   <h1 class="slot-a">Hello</h1>
   <p class="slot-b">World</p>
</div>
```

Then update it with (using jQuery for simplicity, use whatever you want)

```
$('.my-block .slot-a').text(data.title);
$('.my-block .slot-b').text(data.description);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is probably the best solution. Btw, I just found a template engine that works based on CSS classes https://github.com/leonidas/transparency

Comment: Transparency is very nice. They have great documentation and I included it in a talk I gave recently. Regarding this answer however, I'm not sure how applying jQuery answers your original question of how  to avoid creating DOM elements. There's better ways, such as you mentioned, using Transparency. This is a simple example but your code may scale better with templates.

Answer (score 1):

This already has an accepted answer, but that's suggesting using jQuery and writing code to inject your dynamic data. I love jQuery, and sometimes writing code is fine, but this is a good question regarding use of templates. With that in mind, I'll answer your question and use Transparency.js and Mustache.js to demonstrate your options.

You have two choices when it comes to maintaining your elements in the DOM and applying a template engine. They can either start with them there (sent down with your HTML) and use a DOM-based template engine, or you can include the markup in a `script` tag and add them dynamically using a string-based template engine.

Regarding the first option, you can still apply templating using a DOM-based engine such as Transparency or PURE. Transparency actually expects your HTML to already be in the DOM and will manipulate its contents in-place. For simple templates this works great. It's up to you whether you are OK with having to add a class, id, or other identifying attribute to the elements in your markup, which is the drawback. Here is an example to demonstrate:

HTML (serves as template *and* lives in the DOM):

```
<div class="my-block" id="myTemplate"> 
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
    <p class="description"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript (expecting jQuery or jQuery-like library included):

```
$(function() {
    var data = {
        title: 'Hello',
        description: 'World'
    };

    $('#myTemplate').render(data);
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle: [Transparency.js example](http://jsfiddle.net/willslab/Q5B45/1/)

I recommend adding an id to your DOM element so your DOM access is a little faster. That's completely up to you though.

You can also dynamically add the HTML to the DOM. In that case you'll want to include the template some other way. One simple method is using a `script` tag with `type="text/template"`. The browser won't place this text into the DOM, but it will be accessible using a library like jQuery to extract its contents for templating. Here is an example to demonstrate that approach, using Mustache.js.

HTML (including template within `script` tag):

```
<div class="my-block" id="myBlock"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="myTemplate">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ description }}</p>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var data = {
        title: 'Hello',
        description: 'World'
    };

    var template = $('#myTemplate').html();

    var html = Mustache.render(template, data);

    $('#myBlock').html(html);
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle: [Mustache.js example](http://jsfiddle.net/willslab/2KmyG/1/)

In the second example, you need a place-holder div in your DOM to output the templated string, but you don't need to include the `h1` or `p` elements as they will be added dynamically.

There are some clear advantages of each approach. I personally like Transparency.js and its siblings, but it only works for simpler logic-less templates. You also need to be careful adding attributes to your elements. You can re-use those same attributes in your CSS, but you start to couple things a bit and that's dangerous.

Mustache.js is also logic-less, but you don't need to add any extra attributes to your resulting markup, you just need to use the Mustache syntax with double curly braces. However, you need to include your template in a `script` tag, or you can also try using something like Hogan.js to pre-compile Mustache.

I've demonstrated some other examples along with Jade in a Github Pages site I recently published. You can view the templates right on the page, and view the source to see how they were rendered in the JavaScript.

Link: [Templating Sandbox](http://willklein.github.com/templating-sandbox)

More info on Transparency.js: [Try Transparency](http://leonidas.github.com/transparency/)

..and Mustache.js: [Mustache.js on Github](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Call `.text` on each element to set it with your model value.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but how would I find on which exactly elements to call .text as {{title}} and {{description}} can be anywhere.